# copying python packages from normal user folder to root folder

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I am new to administering Linux systems. I have a raspberry pi that doesn't have direct network access. I tried to get the directories of both users and copy a certain package from a normal user to root but that didn't work. if any ways to transfer without downloading the package transfer the root to the user access to libraries.

Comment: I think your question isn't a good fit for this community, you might try superuser.com instead ... but note: no matter *where* you ask for help, remember that people only have the information you GIVE to them. Meaning: "didn't work" isnt a problem description people can help you with. Tell us WHAT EXACTLY you tried, and what exactly happened.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be programming related. You may have more luck on communities https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/.